# Add Object to Array JS

Tags: javascript, mobile, react-native

I cannot add new object to array. Why?

```
  var messagesArray = [
  {message: "Hello", style: styles.nikkiMes},
  {message: "Okkkk", style: styles.userMes}
];

this.state = {
  messagesSource: ds.cloneWithRows(messagesArray.slice()),
  inputMes: ''
};
```

Adding:

```
this.state.messagesArray.push({
  message: this.inputMes,
  style: styles.userMes
});

this.setState({
  messagesSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.messagesArray.slice())
});
```

The error, which i got: undefined is not object (evaluating 'this.state.messagesArray.push')

Comment: what is the `context` of `this`?

Comment: if you inspect `this.state` (e.g. `console.log(this.state);`) right before calling `this.state.messagesArray.push()`, is *messagesArray* a property of `this.state`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Sam Onela in comment above, you don't have messagesArray key within state object or messagesArray is not a property of state object, also ***try to avoid to use push***, that is a mutating function instead try **concat** and **spread** operator.You can try following solutions to overcome the issue

1)

```
 var messagesArray = [
  {message: "Hello", style: styles.nikkiMes},
  {message: "Okkkk", style: styles.userMes}
];

this.state = {
  messagesSource: ds.cloneWithRows(messagesArray.slice()),
  inputMes: ''
};
//these lines of code will not be needed if you are using spread operator
messagesArray.concat({             //replaced push with concat, meassageArray is a global object
  message: this.inputMes,
  style: styles.userMes
});

this.setState({
  messagesSource: ds.cloneWithRows(messagesArray.slice())
  //messagesSource: ds.cloneWithRows([...messageArray, {message: this.inputMes,style: styles.userMes}])  // see how you can directly use spread operator
});
```

2)

```
var messagesArray = [
  {message: "Hello", style: styles.nikkiMes},
  {message: "Okkkk", style: styles.userMes}
];

this.state = {
  messagesSource: ds.cloneWithRows(messagesArray.slice()),
  inputMes: '',
  messagesArray :messagesArray //I included messagesArray  within state
};


this.setState((prevState, props)=>{
 messageArray:[...prevState.messageArray, {message: this.inputMes,style: styles.userMes}]
})

this.setState({
  messagesSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.messagesArray) //first solution will be most fit for your case as messageArray would not have been updated till now
});
```

Comment: Thanks, error don't show now
But ListView in my app don't update...

I have:
sendMes(){
    var ds= new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });

    this.setState({
      messagesSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.messagesArray.concat({message: this.inputMes, style: styles.userMes}).slice())
    });
  }

This function call when button pressed... What i need that code work? :)

Sorry for bad format of comment

Comment: I will suggest you do it with 1st solution, don't keep messgeArray within state(keep it as global variable in your component), add update it before setting the datasource state using concat or push, then do the setState thing

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple typo. You have set the array at state.messagesSource and are trying to add to state.messagesArray which doesn't exist. There is a messagesArray variable but not one available on the state.